# Problemas al integrar archivos .CSS a Django

Tags: html, python, css, django, css3

**AYUDAAAA, ESTOY HACE DÍAS INTENTANDO SOLUCIONAR ESTO PERO NADA, ABAJO LES DEJO EL ENLACE GITHUB CON TODO EL CÓDIGO**

**SI LO DESCARGARON Y LES FUNCIONÓ TODO, TAMBIÉN COMENTEN, PUEDE QUE SEA UN PROBLEMA DE MI VERSIÓN O ALGO ASÍ**

Quiero agregar un enlace de archivos css con Django, pero no funciona, usé lo de `staticfiles` y no me funciona, sólo muestra el html sin estilos, acá dejo como estan organizados los archivos y el código modificado, espero puedan ayudarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ARCHIVO** `static/css/estilos.css`

```
p{
    background-color:darkblue;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**ARCHIVO** `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/estilos.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
    
    <p>PRUEBA DJANGO</p>

</body>

</html>
```

**ARCHIVO** `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def funcion(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

**ARCHIVO** `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from miPaginaweb.views import funcion

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pagina/', funcion)
]
```

**ARCHIVO** `settings.py` (parte static de settings)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),)
```

**DEJO EL ENLACE GITHUB DE TODO EL PAQUETE** https://github.com/KodingT/Django_problema

Comment: intentaste poner en el html {% load static %}, en la primera linea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

espero te encuentres bien, te comento cual es tu error, en tu settings estas definiendo que tus static así:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),)
```

Esto significa que tu directorio static debe de estar al nivel de donde tienes tu manage.py no dentro del directorio de la app miPaginaweb

Para que te cargue de manera correcta en función a tu settings tu estructura debe de ser así:

[image: Estructura correcta del proyecto]

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto fue lo único que cambié y funcionó, tal como lo dijo Kevin Ramirez

Comment: Bueno, no esta duplicada, es como un agregado a lo que me dijo, para que a otros les sirva, porque de verdad este problema lo he visto en muchas consultas

Answer (score 0):

Para que el css funcione, cambiar EN el archivo `setting.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: ¿En qué se diferencia esta respuesta con la ya dada por **KevinRamirezZavalza** y por cierto que fue aceptada como correcta?